# Python Telebot, Как реализовать многоязычного бота?

Tags: python, telebot

Приветствую, пишу бот для telegram на языке **Python** с использованием **telebot**. 
Хотелось бы добавить ему несколько языков помимо русского. Пытался сам обдумать логику бота, но пока у меня не получается.
Создал файл конфигурации **cons.py**:

```
token = "427778629:-oWX9DXZgTX5TXi0I8e0N3s4"
lang = 'ru'
start_msg = 'Здравствуйте, уважаемый клиент!\nВас приветствует бот компании!\nПожалуйста, выберите из меню то что вас интересует.'
order_menu = 'Заказать такси'
info_menu = 'Информация'
exit_menu = 'Покинуть бота'
```

И **main.py:**

```
...
import telebot
import cons
...
bot = telebot.TeleBot(cons.token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def request_contact(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_contact = types.KeyboardButton(text="START", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(button_contact)
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ув.пользовател, для начало работы с ботом нажмите на кнопку 'START'  ", reply_markup=keyboard)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)

def start(message):
    #Переводы
    if cons.lang == 'ru':
      start_msg = 'Здравствуйте, уважаемый клиент!\nВас приветствует бот компании!\nПожалуйста, выберите из меню то что вас интересует.'
      order_menu = 'Заказать такси'
      info_menu = 'Информация'
      exit_menu = 'Покинуть бота'
    elif cons.lang == 'en':
       start_msg = 'Grettings.'
      order_menu = 'Order Taxi'
      info_menu = 'Information'
      exit_menu = 'Leave bot'

  # Главное меню
    start_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, False)
    start_markup.row(' '+cons.order_menu+' ', )
    start_markup.row('ℹ️ '+cons.info_menu+' ℹ️')
    start_markup.row('English', 'Русский язык')
    start_markup.row(' '+cons.exit_menu+' ')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, cons.start_msg, reply_markup=start_markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def main(message): 
    if message.text == 'English':
        cons.lang = 'en'
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Your language is -'+cons.lang+' -', reply_markup=start_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
    elif message.text == 'Русский язык':
        cons.lang = 'ru'
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы выбрали русский язык-'+cons.lang+' -', reply_markup=start_markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start)
```

В моем случаи данный код работает, ну как работает :D  приходится нажимать кнопку на "English" 2 раза и язык бота меняется, но ни только для одного пользователя как должен, и для всех остальных тоже меняется... 
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, благодарю за ранее.

Comment: Наверное, завести базу данных и запоминать id клиентов и выбранный ими язык

Comment: По другому, без базы данных можно же как то реализовать.

Comment: Ну, я могу предложить варианты: 1) хранить в памяти, но это до первого перезапуска бота 2) хранить в файлах: json, xml, <ваш формат> 3) хранить в базе данных, хотя бы в sqlite. Есть конечно и другие варианты, которые я могу придумать, но они вообще дикие

Comment: Вот думаю сделать так как вы и сказали, сохранить в файле типо .ini, при запуске программы сделать проверку ID клиента и сохранят настройки отдельно для каждого пользователя.Благодарю вас за вашу помощь)

Comment: Файлы типа ini это колхоз, извиняюсь... Чем Вас не устраивает sqlite? Работать будет в сотни раз быстрее, и специально предназначено для хранения данных в отличии от ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделай файлы с названиями ru.json, en.json, или питон файлы.

Из объекта message возьми locale, и делай

```
key = 'success_payment_message'
language = message.from_user.locale
translates = json.dumps('{}'.format(language))

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translates[key])
```

Answer (score 2):

как реализовал я:

- создаем файл messages.py в котором все сообщения/обращения хранятся.
- создаем внутри него словари на интересующую нас тематику, например:
  hello_user = {
  'hello_RU': 'Привет',
  'hello_EN': 'Hi'
  ...
  }
- далее импортируем его в main.py
- при старте бота, спрашиваем у пользователя язык общения и записываем в базу данных.
  (Можно узнавать язык автоматически, но работает не для всех стран, допустим Казахстана там нет - а он мне был нужен...)
- бот взаимодействует с пользователем, отвечает на команды и т.д. Но в первую очередь идет запрос в базу данных, узнаем язык пользователя (user_language) и подставляем при каждом удобном случае, например:
  Когда команда /start ответить:
  hello_user[f'hello_{user_language}']
  Соответственно, если user_language == RU, будет подставлено hello_user[f'hello_RU'], а если если user_language == EN будет подставлено hello_user[f'hello_EN'] и т.д.
  Это сделано для того, чтобы не создавать множество свичей (switch_case), вместо:
  """
  if user_language == RU:
  ...
  elif user_language == EN:
  ...
  elif user_language == KG:
  ...
  """
  вместо всего этого нагромождения, у нас получается однострочный код, с минимумом вмешательств в дальнейшем при поддержании и добавлении новых языков